# Spring aspect, pointcut over a protected overloaded method

Tags: java, spring, spring-aspects

I am trying to set a point cut on JmsTemplate class over the method doSend which is protected and overloaded. The one I am interested in is below:

`protected void doSend(MessageProducer producer, Message message) throws JMSException`

My poincut is:

```
@Pointcut("execution(* org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.doSend()) && args(producer,message)")
public void doSend() {
}

@Before("doSend(producer,message)")
public void logMessage(JoinPoint joinPoint, MessageProducer producer, Message message) {
    System.out.println("logMessage() is running!");
    System.out.println("hijacked : " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
    System.out.println("******");
}
```

But I am getting the following warning stopping the server:

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: warning no match for this type name: producer [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]`

I have added the dependencies:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
   <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And have enabled the support for the @Aspect annotation:

`@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)`

Comment: that is a Warning, not an error.

Comment: You are right is a warning. I have updated the question and also added that this warning is stopping the server.

Comment: Warnings don't stop anything.

Comment: There is nothing to match, yur pointcut is wrong. There is no `doSend` without arguments and the `args` is for binding those to method parameters. Finally even if it would match, it wouldn't work. It still is an internal method call that won't pass through a proxy and hence no aspect will be applied.